# words for numbers

Tags: learning, mnemonic

Since words are easier to remember than numbers, you construct a word from each group of numbers and then memorize the word(s)

I would like to learn numbers by words, for example:

```
1=apple
2=red
3=tree
4=for
5=hive
6=mix
7=heaven
8=eternity
9=...
```

Is there a standard for the first 1000 numbers from 0 to 999 so you can easily remember large numbers by memorizing some words or stories?

I found [this article at wikihow.com](http://www.wikihow.com/Memorize-Numbers), but it is not universal enough. One comment explained it very well:

> The idea is that instead of memorizing a number like 5467 (which is random to your brain and will most likely be forgotten in time), you come up with a system of associating that number to a word, and then using a mnemonic device to remember the word, in effect remembering the number. 9167 = BDJK. Since vowels don't count, you can plug them in in anyway to make the letters a word or group of words, like "BaD JoKe". If 9167 is your friend's apartment number, just picture him telling you a "BaD JoKe" - then you remember BDJK, which converts to 9167, etc.
>
> If you string them together, you can make stories out of long numbers. I memorized Pi up to 1,000 digits this way.

Comment: I remember "See, I have a rhyme assisting my feeble brain..." but I can't make heads or tails out of the list given here.

Comment: I clarified the question

Comment: I understand what you are asking now, but the Wiki article associates _letters_ with digits, not _words_ with digits. So I'm still having trouble understanding how your key would help me remember, say, 3866 (tree eternity mix mix?), yet, under the Wiki article, the phrase `move choo choo` might help me remember 3866.

Comment: I searched some more and now I am at the point to create a new list: http://mnemotechnics.org/forums/new-system-to-memorize-numbers-from-0-999-3740.html

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably remember them best if you devise your own number/word pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that memorizing so large a collection of words would be rather more work than remembering the number. But one can create little sayings using words with the number of letters matching the digit to be memorized:-

> How I need a drink, alcoholic of course, after the heavy lectures
>   involving quantum mechanics.

Comment: The advantage of memorizing a collection of words is that once you have it, you can use it to memorise other numbers you come across more easily. Series of words are easier to remember than series of numbers, you see, because the mind makes them into little stories. See also "Correct Horse Battery Staple."